# Pyclewn: Cfile appears last in the debugger when mapping several commands

Tags: debugging, vim, gdb

I would like to use pyclewn in vim in order to debug some of my C++ code. In order to make my day easier I would like to map several commands to one key, for example:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cxx,*.cpp,*.c noremap <F6> 
    \:Pyclewn <CR> :Cfile %<<CR> :Cbreak main <CR>
```

As stated in the manual, I need to have the `async` keword set, so I have

```
let g:pyclewn_args = "--gdb=async"
```

in my `~\.vimrc` file. However, when pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, the gdb will load the file after all the other commands like this

```
Pyclewn version 1.11.py2 starting a new instance of gdb.
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
(...)
(gdb) break main
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) file foo
Reading symbols from foo...done.
(gdb)
```

How can I force `file foo` to come before other commands in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

So, just changed to pyclewn 2.0, in which I don't have the problem any more